# Why isn't this while loop working?

Tags: java, loops, while-loop

```
    try
    {

        Employee test= null;
        while(true)
        {
            test=(Employee)inputStream.readObject();
            list.addANodeToStart(test);

        }


    }
    catch(EOFException e)
    {
        System.out.println("Reached end of file.");
        System.exit(0);
```

Hey guys, I'm having an issue.

In the try block, i have a code to add Employees into a LinkedList. For some reason when i put the while(true) block my whole program doesn't work and it only outputs "reached end of file".

however when i delete the while(true) block it does add just the first Employee, therefore making the rest of my program function but not entirely. Being that i need to add a list of multiple Employees, have a user enter a number and compare that number with the employees number and output the matching employee.

Any ideas?

Comment: You're calling `System.exit(0);` when you reach the end of the file, which causes your program to exit before any other code is reached. It's not the best idea to loop until an exception is thrown, but I suspect your code will work correctly if you remove the `System.exit(0);` and just have an empty catch block.

Comment: Have you tried the contents of list. I think it populates correctly. Just remove system exit from catch block.

Answer (score 0):

Try following:

```
 try
{

    Employee test= null;
    while(true)
    {
        test=(Employee)inputStream.readObject();
        list.addANodeToStart(test);

    }


}
catch(EOFException e)
{
    System.out.println("Reached end of file.");
}

// process the list
```